# Find two-dimensional array closest position to specific point

Tags: php, matrix, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I'm building a PHP application which uses matrix to define tiles, and ultimately, will end up being a map.

I'm currently having trouble understanding how to search the nearest specific value on a two dimensional array for given coordinates.

---

Imagine the following matrix:

[image]

Legend:

- C - Represents the point which I want to find the nearest specific value;
- 0 - Represents a coordinate that hasn't yet been used;
- 1 - Represents a coordinate that is already in use.

---

Could you please help me understand logic or code-wise how can I search for the nearest coordinates that haven't been used (0) to "C"?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not into math things at all, so pardon my vocabulary (open to anyone finding a more straightforward solution) but I will try to solve this by getting the vectors from C to each of the unused points, then search the distance of these vectors.

Given the indexes of C and unused points :

[image]

Store your points with an array with indexes that you can refer to when we will compute the distance of each of them with the C point.

#### Compute the vector from C to each of the unused points

[image]

Vx = (3-2) = 1
Vy = (0-2) = -2

Vector is <1;-2>

#### Compute the distance between each unused points

Distance = sqrt(1² + (-2)²) = sqrt(5) = 2,236

For all the points you will get :

[image]

#### Pickup the nearest point

Search the lowest distance (or sort your results) and get the first nearest point. Its index will be the unused point you're searching for.

#### Example of code implementation with tiles

This is not optimized for purpose.

```php
$tileC       = [2,2]; // Assuming you've searched and found tile C position.
$unusedTiles = [      // Assuming you've searched and found every unused tiles positions.
  0 => [0,0],
  1 => [1,0],
  2 => [3,0],
  3 => [4,0],
  4 => [0,4]
];

$tileDistances = [];

foreach ($unusedTiles as $index => $unusedTile) {
    // Compute the vector.
    $vector = [
        'x' => $unusedTile[0] - $tileC[0],
        'y' => $unusedTile[1] - $tileC[1],
    ];

    // Get the distance from C to the unused tile.
    $tileDistances[$index] = hypot($vector['x'], $vector['y']);
}

// Get the nearest tile indexes.
$nearestTileIndexes = array_keys($tileDistances, min($tileDistances));

var_export($tileDistances);      // The calculated distances.
var_export($nearestTileIndexes); // The nearest tiles.
```

This outputs :

```php
// Distances
array (
  0 => 2.8284271247461903,
  1 => 2.23606797749979,
  2 => 2.23606797749979,
  3 => 2.8284271247461903,
  4 => 2.8284271247461903,
);

// Nearest tiles
array (
  0 => 1, // 1 => [1,0]
  1 => 2, // 2 => [3,0]
);
```

#### Alternative to the distance measurement

Once you computed all the vectors, loop for each of them and search for the closest to 0 for x then y. The first of the remaining points will be the nearest unused points you're searching for. This avoid to compute the `hypot()` of each points.

Comment: Hello Adri, I really appreciate the time you took to put this together. The structure and explanation on the comment seems great, as I clearly understood how you achieved it.

I'm currently implementing a way of doing this by checking the neighbours, and the neighbours of neighbours. I will implement your solution when I finish mine and will benchmark both as it might interesting.

Comment: It's was really interesting to attempt an answer to your question ^^, Going with your neighbours-checking approach seems to be the one to go further. Mine will quickly become slower the more tiles you add.